# Adding custom variables into the request object in Django Middleware without using request.session

Tags: django, request, middleware

Is there a recommended way to pass a variable to all my views? Namely in my case, I want to pass a UserProfile object that Foreign Keys a django.contrib.auth.models.User object. I find most if not all my views need to pull the UserProfile object and putting it in Middleware seems like the way to go. It seems like I could do something like the following (I've seen a couple of solutions online that suggest it):

```
request.session['userprofile'] = userprofile_object
```

I don't like this because if my UserProfile model ever has a non-serializable field, it would break request.session.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the `AuthenticationMiddleware` enabled, you will have a `user` object in all your views. To get the profile all you need to do is call `user.get_profile` in your view. For example, to output the id of the profile, you would do `{{ user.get_profile.id }}`.

If you would prefer not to call the get_profile function of the user object each time, you can add arbitrary items to your request. You would create a new middleware which would simply set

```
request.user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
```

Then just register that middleware in your settings.py and you should be good to go. I have used this method in the past for getting user geolocation data pinned to the request object.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal depends on the assumption that userprofile objects only matter when users are already logged in so you can get the logged in user via `request.user`.
It should be possible to get the userprofile by travelling the foreignkey key relation in reverse like this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    request.user.userprofile_object_set.all() #gets all related userprofile objects
else:
   #...
```

Comment: Yeah, there are multiple ways to get the UserProfile object. You could also do UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user), but that doesn't answer the question, how do you pass it to a view?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question then. Because every view gets request passed in as first argument, there would be no need to "pass" the profile into the view. If you want a variable with the userprofile available on every template, you could consider a custom context_processor which puts the userprofile_object into a variable.

Comment: I believe `prof = request.user.userprofile_object_set.all()[0]` will hit the database every time it's called?